# How can I host a sub domain

Tags: iis-7, web-hosting

Hello I have a website hosted on remote desktop. ("mywebsite.com") 
I want to host another web app with domain "app.mywebsite.com". I created a website in IIS but its not working. What's the configuration setting I need to do make this working ?

(I use IIS7) first app(mywebsite.com) is hosted before. I downt know anything about.
I just created an app and want to host it in same remote desktop with "app.mywebsite.com" alias.

there is an warrning seem on basic settings > Test settings pane
Error message is : "The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again."

How can I fix this ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [add a binding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=WS.10%29.aspx):

- [Open IIS Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
- In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node in the tree, and then click to select the site for which you want to add a binding.
- In the Actions pane, click Bindings.
- In the Site Bindings dialog box, click Add.
- In the Add Site Binding dialog box, add the binding information and then click OK.